# Get domain from range using ScaleBand

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using `d3.scaleBand()` with string domain and a decimal output, into d3.js v4

I'm interested to retrieve the "key" from the range decimal value.

```
var xscale = d3.scaleBand() // v4
  .domain(["a","b","c","d","e"])
  .range([0, 5])

console.log(xscale("c")) // return 2
console.log(xscale.magicfunction(2)) // return c
```

Is there a way to do that in d3 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50846323/9938317

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D3 ordinal scales don't have `invert` methods, but you can create your own.

Once I saw a clever alternative using a `scaleQuantile`, along these lines:

```
xscale.invert = function(x) {
    var domain = this.domain();
    var range = this.range()
    var scale = d3.scaleQuantize().domain(range).range(domain)
    return scale(x)
};
```

Then, in your case, just use:

```
console.log(xscale.invert(2)) // returns c
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var xscale = d3.scaleBand() // v4
  .domain(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
  .range([0, 5]);

xscale.invert = function(x) {
  var domain = this.domain();
  var range = this.range()
  var scale = d3.scaleQuantize().domain(range).range(domain)
  return scale(x)
}

d3.range(0, 5.2, 0.2).forEach(function(d) {
  console.log(d.toFixed(2) + " corresponds to: " + xscale.invert(d))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

PS: This solution will ignore any padding you have in the scale.